# transform an array of objects into an array containing arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
```

An object looks like this:

```
{ 
  id: ...
  name: ...
  association: {
    id: ...
  }
}
```

I'd like to collect objects with the same association id and get a array like this:

```
[ [ { ... association { id: 1} }, { ... association { id: 1} } ], [ { ... association { id: 2 } } ] ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a function that will return an array of objects that contain an association id that is provided?

Comment: I just want to gather the different objects that contain the same value in the association id property

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a function that will return an array of objects that contain an association id that is provided

```
const data = [{...},{...},{...}]
const getByAssociationID = (source, id) => source.filter(obj => obj.association.id === id)
console.log(getByAssociationID(data, id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should group the data as you describe

```
function groupByAssociation(data) {
    return data.reduce((list, value) => {
        let added = false;

        list.forEach(group => {
            if(group[0].association.id === value.association.id) {
                group.push(value);
                added = true;
            }
        });

        if(!added) {
            list.push([ value ]);
        }

        return list;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` to build and object with keys as `association.id` and values are accumulated.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "blah",
    association: {
      id: "a1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "foo",
    association: {
      id: "a2"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "test",
    association: {
      id: "a2"
    }
  }
];

const process = data => {
  const obj = {};
  data.forEach(item => {
    const aId = item.association.id;
    const newItem = obj[aId] || [];
    newItem.push(item);
    obj[aId] = newItem;
  });
  return Object.values(obj);
};

console.log(process(data));
```